# Is there a website you can send a request to with specified delay?

Tags: web, delay

I'm looking for a website I can send a request to and specify some amount of delay in the query string, like:

http://delaywebsite.com?delay=5

and the website will wait 5 seconds before responding with a 200.

This is a surprisingly hard thing to google for. I'm aware this would be very easy to implement but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does exactly that:

```
curl -I https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/5
```

Reference (Dynamic data):

https://nghttp2.org/httpbin